# VBA for excel, WIth to include a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple Sub routine to format selected cells in a certain way
I want to have a condition in the process, so that selected cells that match the condition will receive a certain format, and others, another format

I can do it with a simple loop, but my question is specifically for `with`

Is there something like:

```
With Selection
    value > 10 THEN HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

Comment: `IF value > 10 THEN`

Comment: `With` is for changing multiple properties of the same object, you can use standard `If`instructions inside, but not the way you wrote it, just standard `If` syntax

Comment: inside the with ?

Comment: I'll write a proper answer

Comment: Can’t you just use conditional formatting in excel, instead of using VBA for this?

Comment: `Selection` can be something else than a range... It must be checked from this point of view. It should  be avoided if possible. If you need it/insist, try using `ActiveCell`. Then, a property of an object in a `With ... End With` must start with a dot `.`. Only in this way it belongs to the respective object. Finally, a condition must start with `If`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditions inside a With. Just use the regular syntax.
Let's say for example you want to change the value of cell A1 to "my value", and if cell A2 value is > 10, then change the horizontal alignment of cell A1.
This would look like :

```
With Sheets("nameofasheet").Range("A1")
    .Value = "my Value"
    If Sheets("nameofasheet").Range("A2").Value > 10 Then
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End If
End With
```